# Play Billing Library v1.0 order status

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented inapp purchase for one of my android application using

```
com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0
```

as described [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html#retrieve)

I am checking user have purchased SKU or not with below code

```
  mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponse) {
            if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                Log.e("billing",""+billingResponse);
                Log.e(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: " + billingResponse);
                Purchase.PurchasesResult result = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                if(result.getPurchasesList().size() > 0) {
                    Log.e("Purchased Product", result.getPurchasesList().get(0).getSku());
                    if (result.getPurchasesList().get(0).getSku().equals(constant.sku))
                        constant.ad_removed = true;
                    Log.e("code",""+result.getResponseCode());
                }
            }

            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: " + billingResponse);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Log.e(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()");
        }
    });
```

Its working fine but I am providing benefit of premium app if user have purchased SKU but what happen if user ask for refund and we refund user ? I have tried to refund one order and its showing in my console as refunded but still user have premium benefit due to billing response show user have purchased that SKU. any one have idea to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the status is refunded, you can consume the product so that the product will no longer exist.

But apparently, there is no such method to check if a purchase has been refunded in Play Billing Library v1.0. Probably it will be added in the future.

For now, when refunding the purchase, store the transaction ids in your server and make an API to check whether the purchase has been refunded or not. Then in the app, make call to the server with the purchase details. If the server returns refunded, consume the product.

You may also use the Void Purchases API for the same purpose:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for answer. Whats is the method for check order status like refunded ? Thanks

Comment: There no any method like refunded in library

Comment: Hi ! Thanks again for your answer. I think you are answering with Billing Library V3. You can see that I am using newly launched library. its show me that unable to resolve inventory.